# How do I differentiate between 2 different solutions of the same name in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have 2 different solution files which have the same name in 2 different locations on my drive. I have 2 different instances of Visual Studio 2010 open and have a solution in each of them open. I'm working on both of them at the same time and I keep getting mixed up about which is which.

Without having to right click on one of my folders in my solution explorer and "Opening Folder in Windows Explorer," is there a way to tell the difference between the 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the only way to do this will be to show the path of the solutions in the title bar
This [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) discussion should help you :
[Display solution/file path in Visual Studio IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505/display-solution-file-path-in-visual-studio-ide)

Answer (score 1):

Install the visual studio color theme editor using the extension manager in Tools > Extension Manager...

Then simply go to the toolbar and select Theme > |Pick a theme| on one of the instances.

Now you will have completely different looking Visual studio instances opened.

Comment: In which VS version this worked for you? Wherever I tried that, all open instances changed their theme together.

Comment: I now used an extension called Rename Visual Studio Window Title. This works just as well.

Comment: No problem with changing window title, but I'm interested in that color change you described.

Comment: @miroxlav perhaps the sync you saw is due to roaming your VS account settings? Did you ever work it out?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS2010 or above you can you the extension "Visual Studio Window Title Changer".   Install this and use the following 'Window Title Setup' expression to display the solution path:

'sln_dir + "/" + orig_title'

Use the extension manager to download and install the extension.  Details of the extension and how to use it can be found here:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2e8ebfe4-023f-4c4d-9b7a-d05bbc5cb239?SRC=VSIDE

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 Symbolic Links are supported. 
By linking a solution with a different Name, VS will show as a different solution in the title, but update the original solution file.

```
mklink "new Name.sln" "normal name.sln"
```